# Redirect tex.print output to a file

Tags: luatex

I want to redirect `tex.print` output to a file to collect and reuse the produced `LaTeX` material :

the `mwe` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

essai

\directlua{require("essai.lua")}

\directlua{ a = "Hello word \\dots" }

\directlua{ to_file ( a ) }

\end{document}
```

and the lua script called `essai.lua` :

```
function to_file ( x )
    local file_name = "Foo"

    out = io.open( file_name .. ".tex", 'w' )

    tex.print = out:write

    out:write ( "\\documentclass{article}" )
    out:write ( "\\begin{document}")
    tex.print ( x )
    out:write ( "\\end{document}" )
    io.close( out )
end
```

The error message is :

> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)...2/texmf-dist/te
> x/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:391: error loading module essai.lua f
> rom file ./essai.lua:
> ./essai.lua:9: function arguments expected near 'out'

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Does this code already work, or not? Do you get errors? Which part works and which part does not? Or is it an answer and you forgot to post the question?

Comment: This example doesn't work and is the purpose of the question. As you see one of the out:write that write normally to a file is remplaced by a `tex.print`. I have some complex document mostly produced using lua output, and I want to preserve the latex output to reuse it. It is why I want to save it to a file.

Comment: Well this one is completely about Lua programming instead of TeX programming, but alright.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can overwrite the function definition (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4510038/):

```lua
function to_file ( x )
    local file_name = "Foo"

    out = io.open( file_name .. ".tex", 'w' )

    tex.print = function(trp)
        out:write(trp)
        out:write("\n")
    end

    out:write ( "\\documentclass{article}\n" )
    out:write ( "\\begin{document}\n")
    tex.print ( x )
    out:write ( "\\end{document}\n" )
    io.close( out )
end
```

Resulting `Foo.tex` with your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello word \dots
\end{document}
```